# Is every proof an array of implications?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, constructive-mathematics

I want to prove an implication but I don't know how I can do it without using contradiction. Is there a way to rewrite the contradiction in logical terms, only using the implication "$\Rightarrow$" sign?

What I know is that $0\neq c(b)=x(b),\forall b\in B_0$ and $0=x(b),\forall b\in B\backslash B_0$. I also know that $0\neq x_{|A}(b)=x(b),\forall b\in A$ and $x(b)=0,\forall b\in B\backslash A$. I want to show that this implies $A=B_0$. I am not sure if this is necessary to say but $A,B_0$ are subsets of $B$.

To my understanding "constructive" proofs are proofs only using the implication sign.

I was wondering whether the contradiction is just an abbreviation of an array of implications (i.e. proofs by contradictions are also contructive).

To show the equality of the two sets I need to verify the implications under the assumption that $b\in B$

$b\in A\Rightarrow b\in B_0$

$b\in B_0\Rightarrow b\in A$

But I don't know how I can show the first implication constructively.

If $b\in A$ then $x(b)\neq 0$. Then I would have said if I assume $b$ is not in $B_0$ then $x(b)=0$ which is a proof by contradiction.

Is there a way only using implication signs to prove the statement, can the contradiction be written as implication?

Comment: Constructive proofs are proofs in [constructive logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intuitionistic_logic) which can be viewed as a sublogic of classical logic. Constructive logic is not restricted to only using implications. Minimal logic is what you get if the only connective is $\to$ and only rules are $\to$ introduction and $\to$ elimination. This is *a* constructive logic, but it is weaker than what constructive logic usually means (which includes, at least, the $\bot$ connective and $\bot$ elimination, i.e. the principle of explosion).

Comment: @Derek Elkins I have read  something on wikipedia about proofs by contradiction https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_contradiction it says that if we want to prove a statement $P$ we can do that by showing that the implication $P\rightarrow \bot$ which is equiivalent $(\equiv)$ to $\neg\neg P$ which is then equivalent to $P$. Can you explain why the contradictionproof is not constructive because I was using only implications in my argumentation and you said this is *a* constructive logic. But on the other hand I have always heard that proofs by contradiction are **not** contructive